# How to disable delete for JoinTable?

Tags: jpa

I have problem with disable delete for JoinTable.

```
@Entity 
class Employee
{
     @Id
     Long id;

     @ManyToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH } )
     @JoinTable( name = "Employee2AddressOracleView",
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "employee_id" ), 
                 inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "address_id" ) 
     private Address address;
)
```

Address for Employee is calculated in View. It works, I can load Employee but when I want delete employee JPA want delete row from view to. It is possible to disable this delete query?

JPA query in console:

```
delete from Employee where employee_id = ?
delete from Employee2AddressOracleView where employee_id = ?
```

Comment: The solution for this problem is hear : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=985505

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has a link to hibernate forums which are dead. I managed to pull the link out on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170113182538/https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=985505&sid=dc550e634938fa271b76ecf60119d189).

The solution is to create a separate entity representing the join table, mapped to the view, instead of using @JoinTable.

Main entity mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Main")
   public class MainEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   private Integer id;

   @OneToOne
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   private JoinTableViewEntity joinEntity;
}
```

Join table view entity mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableView")
public class JoinTableViewEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   private Integer mainEntityId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="other_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
   private OtherEntity other;
}
```

It also works without updateable and insertable attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EclipseLink you can use a DescriptorCustomizer to make the mapping readOnly.